# org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet class not found

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I've some issue starting my Tomcat under Eclipse IDE. I followed all instruction to create a MVC web application using Spring Tutorial (actually not only one, just to be sure I'm doing right) and, when I start Tomcat from Eclipse I've this problem:

```
Error loading WebappClassLoader
  context: /CG
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@70ba9340
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
```

I tried to check on internet for some similar problem but all solution proposed doesn't works. I checked my classpath and all lib are available, I manually copied all jar to the WEB-INF/lib folder but still not working.

I included:

```
org.springframework.asm-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.context-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.context-support-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.core-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.test-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.web-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.web-servlet-3.1.0.M1.jar
```

May you help me, please? I'm really frustrated about this issue....

tnx,
Andrea

Comment: Advice: If you're just learning Spring, you shouldn't be using the 3.1 milestone builds, you'll just get confused.  Stick with 3.0.x.

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: @skaffman thanks for the advice, I'm using 3.0.5 now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy all spring releated jars into {tomcat_installation}/lib for tomcat 6 and for tomcat 5.x {tomcat_installation}/shared/lib.

Answer (score 3):

`DispatcherServlet` is typically in the `spring-webmvc-${version}.jar`.

I suggest using Maven or Ivy to manage those dependencies for you.

Comment: I'll use also Maven, I'm a newbie on Java tools